# I am getting exception while Pairing to bluetooth device from flutter_bluetooth_serial package

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, flutter-dependencies, android-bluetooth

I am using flutter_Bluetooth_Serial package for connecting to bluetooth. while connecting to other bluetooth device i am getting following exception from flutter. can you please tell me how to rectify this eception.
`I/flutter (26347): PlatformException(connect_error, read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1, java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1

for connecting i wrote code as below:-
BluetoothConnection connection = await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(address);

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take our [tour] and read about [ask] questions. It would help a lot if you would [edit] your question to add a [mre] inside a [code block].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.